# laravel markdown email render hrml in inbox

Tags: php, laravel, markdown, html-email

Recently I upgrade Laravel to 6.13.0. Before the upgrade, my markdown email template was good in design. After upgrade, I am trying to send Laravel Mail in markdown format. But when I test it with MailDev it is rendering HTML format.

My email template looks like.

```
@component('mail::message')
   @component('mail::panel')
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 bg-gray">
            <span>Time</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-gray">
            <span class="badge">{{ date('jS F g:ia', strtotime($signal->signal_time)) }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
   @endcomponent
@endcomponent
```

then its look like this in MailDev..

[image]

What can I do now?

Answer (score 11):

I get the solution for this issue. recently Laravel has moved CommonMark as their markdown template. it doesn't convert space. what's why my email template is shown as HTML markup. Now, what has to do to fix it.

I removed all space from my email template files like this.

```
@component('mail::message')
@component('mail::panel')
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6 bg-gray">
<span>Time</span>
</div>
<div class="col-6 bg-gray">
<span class="badge">{{ date('jS F g:ia', strtotime($signal->signal_time)) }}</span>
</div>
</div>
 @endcomponent
@endcomponent
```

and that fixed my issue. I think someone gets help from this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Markdown considers indented stuff to be code blocks. So, we just have to de-indent everything.

**Example:**

```
@component('mail::message')
<h3>Hi {{ $name }}</h3>
<h2>You are invited to join as a member. Here is your login credentials:</h2>
<br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>{{ $email }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>{{ $password }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
@component('mail::button', ['url' => $url])
    <span>Login Here</span>
@endcomponent

<h4>Thanks,</h4>

@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and in my case, i have fixed it with writing all stuff with a @ in one line, so as an example:

File: `resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php`

Before (not working, showing `linkduration` in mail):

```
@lang('mail.welcome.linkduration', 
  ['linkduration' => $linkduration]
)
```

After (working)

```
@lang('mail.welcome.linkduration', ['linkduration' => $linkduration])
```

I hope, this will help

Answer (score 0):

The default panel component strips HTML.

If you want to override the default `mail::` component namespace you have to publish the vendor files.

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail`

Then if you look in `resources/views/vendor/mail/markdown/` you will see the comonents which you can edit.

`panel.blade.php` is just `{{ $slot }}`, change to `{!! $slot !!}` to allow unfiltered html.

Also, as a side note, if you are using Markdown, you probably don't want to be using complicated bootstrap & HTML directly anyway.

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#customizing-the-components